# Como inicializar form utilizando valor vindo de um service em angular

Tags: angular, api

Estou retornando da minha *API* um número inteiro, e então, com o angular preciso mostrar esse valor como padrão nesta tag:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="pacienteId" class="form-control">
```

Sei que para inicializar formulários com valores de um objeto utiliza-se `[(ngModel)]="objeto.propriedade"` porém como eu poderia retornar da minha API esse número inteiro utilizando o service do angular?

Este é o meu service:

```
currentId(): any {
  return this.http.get<number>(`${this.baseURL}/currentId`)
}
```

Comment: o que retorna dessa url? `${this.baseURL}/currentId`?

Comment: Retorna um número inteiro

Comment: No component onde chama esse service você pode criar uma função para chamá-lo: ex: `currentId().then( response => this.pacienteId = response )` Ai chamar a função que você criar no init do component

Comment: Eu quero mostrar esse número inteiro que retorna desta URL sempre que inicializar o formulário

Comment: na verdade seria no seu form: `currentId().then( response => this.seuForm.pacienteId.setValue( response ) )`

Comment: Não use códigos em imagem, veja [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Answer (score 3):

Considerando o comentário que você fez que sua URL retorna um número inteiro e então seria mais ou menos assim

**service.ts**

```js
currentId(){
   return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}/currentId`)
}
```

No component onde você chama aquele service e monta o formulário seria mais ou menos assim:

**component.ts**

```js
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export class SeuComponent implements OnInit {
  formCad: FormGroup
  constructor(private _seuService: SeuService) { }

   ngOnInit(){
        this.formCad = new FormGroup({
                pacienteId: new FormControl('')
             })

         this.getcurrentId()
    }
    getcurrentId(){
         this._seuService
             .currentId()
             .subscribe( response => {
                    this.formCad.controls.pacienteId.setValue( response)
              })
      }
}
```

Espero que possa ajudar

Comment: Ajudou muito cara, muito obrigado, só fiz uma simples modificação. No lugar do 'then()' coloquei o método subscribe.

Comment: Isso mesmo.... eu que esqueci rs